Can a jointly continuous function on $X \times Y$ can be interpretted as a continuous function from $X$ to $C(Y)$?
Given locally compact spaces X and Y, must the following hold $C_b(X \times Y) \subseteq C_b(X, C_b(Y))$? We may assume $C_b(Y)$ is endowed with the topology of the sup-norm.
Given $f \in C_b(X \times Y)$, it makes sense that $f$ can be interpreted as a bounded function from $X$ to $C_b(Y)$. My difficulty comes in justifying the continuity.
Given $x \in X$, we can define $f_x(y) = f(x, y)$. In that vein, I've tried to consider if $x_i \to x$, then I should show $f_{x_i} \to f_{x}$ via the sup-norm. However, if I assume $\epsilon > 0$, I want to find $i_0 \in I$ such that $i \geq i_0$ implies
$$|| f_{x_i} - f_{x} ||_{\infty} = \text{sup} \{ |f_{x_i}(y) - f_x(y)| ~ \mid ~ y \in Y\}= \text{sup} \{ |f(x_i, y) - f(x, y)| ~ \mid ~ y \in Y\} $$
I do not know how to proceed because $i_0$ cannot depend on the choice of $y \in Y$.
Does anyone have any tips here? Is my conjecture even true? Any help would be appreciated. This is not an assignment question.

What does $C_b$ mean?

@TobySaunders-A'Court I think they probably mean $C_b(X \times Y, \mathbb{R})$ not $C_b(X \times Y, X \times Y)$.

@TobySaunders-A'Court. I meant $C_b(X \times Y, \mathbb{C})$, but the answer won't depend on whether it's functions to $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$.

This is not true. For example, let $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $Y = \mathbb{N}_+$. Fix an enumeration $\{q_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}_+}$ of rational numbers in which each rational number appears infinitely many times. Let $f: X \times Y \to \mathbb{C}$ be defined by,
$$f(r, n) = \begin{cases}
n(r - q_n + 1) &, \, \mathrm{if} \, q_n - 1 < r < q_n - 1 + \frac{1}{n}\\
1 &, \, \mathrm{if} \, q_n - 1 + \frac{1}{n} \leq r \leq q_n + 1 - \frac{1}{n}\\
n(q_n + 1 - r) &, \, \mathrm{if} \, q_n + 1 - \frac{1}{n} < r < q_n + 1\\
0 &, \, \mathrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
Since $Y$ is discrete, one easily verifies that $f$ is continuous. It has range between $0$ and $1$, so it’s also bounded. However, I claim that whenever $x_1 \neq x_2 \in X$, we have $\|f_{x_1} - f_{x_2}\|_\infty = 1$. Indeed, assume WLOG that $x_1 < x_2$. Then we may pick $q \in (x_1, x_2) \cap \mathbb{Q}$. We may also assume $q + 1 > x_2$. Since each rational number appears in the list $\{q_n\}$ infinitely many times, we may choose $n$ s.t. $q_n = q + 1$ and furthermore $q + \frac{1}{n} < x_2$. Then by definition of $f$, we see that $f_{x_1}(n) = f(x_1, n) = 0$ but $f_{x_2}(n) = f(x_2, n) = 1$. This proves the claim.
Thus, the map $x \ni X \to f_x \in C_b(Y)$ is not continuous.

that's quite an amazing counter example. Thank you for sharing.
